# How can i combine two gulp tasks

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, gulp-concat

I am using `gulp` to compile my typescript files and create the `output.js` file.

Is it possible to have a single task which compiles typescript file and concatenates it with angular libraries?

Here's what my current file looks like (below). First it's running a typescript task which creates the `output.js` file and then it runs a scripts task which concats the script plugin files and `output.js`.

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp')

var paths = {
  distScriptsDir: '../../Themes/mastter/Scripts',
  srcScriptsPlugins: [
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
    'node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
    'node_modules/angular-translate/dist/angular-translate.min.js',
    'node_modules/angular-translate/dist/angular-translate-loader-url/angular-translate-loader-url.min.js',
    'node_modules/angular-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
    'Scripts/angular-sticky.min.js',
    'Scripts/dragme.js',
    'Scripts/jasny-bootstrap.min.js',
    'node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js',
    'node_modules/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js'
  ],
  srcScriptsFile: [
    'output.js'
  ]
};


//typescript
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
  var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
  var tsResult = gulp.src( 'all.ts')
    .pipe(ts({
      noImplicitAny: true,
      out: 'output.js'
    }));
  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});

// scripts task
gulp.task('scripts', function () {

  var concat = require('gulp-concat'),
      plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
      uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

  return gulp.src(paths.srcScriptsPlugins.concat(paths.srcScriptsFile))
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (e) {
          console.log(e.toString());
          this.emit('end');
      }
    }))
  //    .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(concat('main.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distScriptsDir));

});

// default task
gulp.task('default', [
 'typescript',
  'scripts'
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a watch tasks for this that has a bunch of `gulp.watch` inside it.  One for watching the .ts change and run the typescript compiler that will output a js file in whatever location and another `gulp.watch` that watches the .js files and run script task.  In that case, things will get automated by the watch and you don't have to combine the task into one task.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['dir/*.ts','otherdir/*.ts',...], ['typescript']);
    gulp.watch(['dir/*.js','otherdir/*.js',...], ['scripts']); //make sure to include the .ts result folder...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence).  Below is a simple example.

```js
gulp.task('task1', function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('task1 is done');
    callback()
  }, 1000);
});

gulp.task('task2', function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('task2 is done');
    callback()
  }, 2000);
});

gulp.task('tk12', function(callback) {
  return runSequence('task1', 'task2', callback);
});
```